# Opencart: Master product list, multiple slave sites possible?

Tags: opencart

One of my B2B partners asked me a question today. I enjoyed the whooshing sound it made as it went over my head, since I've never even looked at a line of code from OpenCart. I suggested to him that I could post it here, where the experts live.

**Check it out:**

> I am looking at opencart as a solution for a development project that we have and I wanted to know if anyone knows if it is possible to setup OpenCart as a master/slave configuration. All sites will be on the same server with different IPs and different domain names so I would be using the same core database for the master site and each slave/product site.
>
> What I am looking for is a way to manage all the products from one login so we don't have multiple shops that need to be managed. Is there a way to group products so I could group them by brand so they are only shown on the site they are meant for? I just wanted to check with the community to see if anyone is familiar with this setup.
>
> [image: Fig 1.]

Answer (score 0):

It is supported since OC 1.4.9 I guess - and it's called *multistore*.

You have one eshop, one administration, one database, one set of products, categories, etc.

You manage the data in the *master* administration and set which data is visible at what *slave* store. Each *slave* store has to be an alias domain/subdomain to the main *master* domain.

Result: it is possible and not so hard to achieve. You can then have different settings (localization, theme, product settings, order settings, ...) per *slave* store.

Comment: You can actually have multiple domains not just subdomains - both are allowed as long as you can point them to the document root folder

Comment: @JayGilford OK, didn't try that, nice to know. Will edit my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Further, it supports multi domains, multi languages and multi currencies. With regards to the answer. shadyyx has already posted. I am furthering with regards to the technical side.

```
web server loadbalanced via dns:

opencart webserver1
php, nginx, apc, memcache
multiple stores on this server. The files and content is cloned to two other servers and they clone and sync every 1 hour. They get hits for high traffic.
opencart webserver2 - slave, cloned of webserver1
opencart webserver3 - slave, cloned of webserver1

cdn1 - rackspace cloud files - images, css, javascript
cdn2 - rackspace cloud files - xml, html, videos

database loadbalanced:

database mysql master server 1

database mysql slave server 2
database mysql slave server 3
```

So you can see. Opencart is a good solution to go with. Handling multiple stores on the same servers and or different servers. Working together.