# OpenCart multiple separate stores, universal customer/product database?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I'm currently running a setup that involves multiple separate merchants with their own OpenCart stores and administrators (merchants), and one main "mall" site. All of these run on one domain (stores use subdomains). What I want to do are the following:

1. Universal user accounts (one time registration, log in on all stores). I was thinking of exporting the oc_customers and related tables out to the "mall" database, and create a custom registration form on the mall website. I was able to somewhat achieve this on OpenCart 1.4.x, but there are several more tables on the latest version, and I want to make sure I do it right. Anyone know how one would go around to doing this?
2. Allow the mall website to display all products from all stores. Originally I used a cron job to import XML feeds from each separate store and merge in any changes to the main products table. What I really want is to make this more real-time, and much neater so I don't have to "sync" changes every time a product is added/modified/deleted.

Sorry for the wall of text. Hoping for some guidance. Thanks! :)

Comment: Facing the same issue right now. Here's what I found: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15396227/722036 I guess it's called multi-store and it's supposed to make multiple stores use the same database

Comment: Yeah, but multi-store is not multi-vendor, if you know what I mean...